# How to call methods outside of a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I call `myfunc` and `myotherfunc` below outside of the class?

```
class Accounting::Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def myfunc
    return true
  end

  class << self
    def myotherfunc
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`myfunc` is an *instance method*, so you first need an instance and then you can call the function:

```
invoice = Accounting::Invoice.new
invoice.myfunc
```

`myotherfunc` is *class method*, so you just call it on directly on the class object:

```
Accounting::Invoice.myotherfunc
```

By the way, this answer is not specific to Rails; it applies to any Ruby program.

This post may be helpful (I didn't read the whole thing):
http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: i upvoted your answer but had something to add for @user662503 that wasn't answer worthy. To the OP, the `class << self` syntax is a shortcut typically used to define multiple class methods at once. It is equivalent to writing `def self.myotherfunc return false end`

Comment: @Caley Woods, thanks for the comment, that is a good thing to know.